# Generating Failure in junit4

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am trying to understand which call causes Error and Which causes failures in Junit4. Until Junit3,

Failure can be created using

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
```

And Error with

```
junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals
```

But with the deprecation of ***junit.framework.Assert***, which is not moved to ***org.junit.Assert***, I am not able to find a way in junit4 to throw a failure. Anything I try with org.junit.Assert (even Assert.fail() ) , JUnit considers it as Error.

**Any idea on how to properly generate failures in Junit4 style tests?**

**Update**

I figured out that there is a std.err at the end of XML generated by JUnit ant target.

```
<system-err>TEXT here</system-err>
```

and I suspected this is the cause that making it ERROR instead of Failure. But when I cleared all sys.err, it still marking it ERROR.

Comment: "JUnit considers it as Error" What do you mean - at compile time, or runtime?

Comment: We run a test and generate an HTML report. In the HTML report, The assertion failure comes as ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [Assert.assertThat](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) for getting assertion failure

> ```
> assertThat(0, is(1)); // fails:
> assertThat(0, is(not(1))) // passes
> ```

It may not what you need, but also JUnit 4 has [ComparisonFailure](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/index.html?org/junit/ComparisonFailure.html)

> Thrown when an assertEquals(String, String) fails. Create and throw a ComparisonFailure manually if you want to show users the difference between two complex strings.

Comment: Even the ComparisonFailure is being considered as Error as i have checked. XML report  generated with ant junit target consider it as ERROR.

Comment: @Krishnom you mean like when using `Assert.assertThat` ?https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)

Comment: Yupp. Its like  <testcase ... ><error message="expected ... but was: ... </error></testcase> ... at <Location where we have Assert.assertEquals() >

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. The only solution I have found so far is to use a try block followed by

```
    catch (AssertionError ae) {
       fail(ae.toString());
     }
```

But I can see downsides to this and I have seen many people say this is bad practice. Unfortunately I don't see another way around it when using ant to make a report.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.